# Can you make a beracha during hiccups?

Tags: halacha, blessing, medicine

If one has hiccups, and needs to make a beracha, is it a problem?

There are high chances that some words will be split and mispronounced...

Comment: What sort of beracha? If it's on food, you can hardly enjoy it with the hiccups. If it's for the glass of water you are drinking to "drown" the hiccups, it doesn't need a beracha. If it's for tefilla, can you concentrate with the hiccups?

Comment: I was thinking birkat hamazon or some other after food beracha (time most likely to have hiccups)

Comment: http://www.kipa.co.il/ask/show/284661-%D7%AA%D7%A4%D7%99%D7%9C%D7%94-%D7%95%D7%A9%D7%99%D7%94%D7%95%D7%A7%D7%99%D7%9D

Comment: @sam your link seems not in accord with the answer from Avrohom. But then again in your case it seems the person was a shaliah tsibour for the kaddish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Halachipedia has the laws of Birkat Hamazon](http://halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Birkat_HaMazon). Hiccups are not mentioned but the following seems relevant:

Someone who is drunk

> One may say Birkat HaMazon even if one is slightly drunk and is unable
>   to speak properly but still would be able to speak before a king,
>   however, if one is unable to speak properly and can’t speak before a
>   king one should try to say Birkat HaMazon before reaching that point,
>   but one may still say Birkat HaMazon. [S”A 185:4-5, Mishna Brurah
>   185:6]

I deduce that if you would not speak before a king with hiccups like that, it is better (in this case) to wait till the hiccups go (assuming it is within the time to still say Birkat HaMazon – see the relevant halochos). But one may still say Birkat HaMazon. 
Of course CYLOR.

Answer (score -2):

Moses had a speech impediment. If God had a problem with involuntarily split and mispronounced words, he would have picked another prophet.

If you are completely unintelligible, it may be a problem for others to answer amen if they can't actually hear the words.

Comment: The speech impediment was permanent. Hiccups go away (normally). I did not downvote.